# Jasmine: How to get name of current test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

Is there a way of getting the name of the currently running test?

Some (heavily simplified) code may help explain. I want to avoid the duplication of `"test1" / "test2"` in the calls to `performTest`:

```
describe("My test category", function () {

    function performTest(uniqueName, speed) {
        var result = functionUnderTest(uniqueName, speed);
        expect(result).toBeTruthy();
    }

    it("test1", function () {
        performTest("test1", "fast");
    });

    it("test2", function () {
        performTest("test2", "slow");
    });
});
```

---

**UPDATE**
I see the information I need is in:

```
jasmine.currentEnv_.currentSpec.description
```

or probably better:

```
jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.description
```

Comment: Just for your information `expect(result).toBeTruthy` won't test anything, `expect(result).toBeTruthy()` will do the test.

Comment: Look at this answer for adding a Jasmine Custom Reporter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48664485/293280

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.description
```

Comment: In Jasmine 2, this is no longer available.

Comment: @strongriley: I've added in a Jasmine 2 solution. It's a little annoying, but it gets the job done relatively easily.

Answer (score 10):

It's not pretty (introduces a global variable) but you can do it with a custom reporter:

```
// current-spec-reporter.js

global.currentSpec = null;

class CurrentSpecReporter {

  specStarted(spec) {
    global.currentSpec = spec;
  }

  specDone() {
    global.currentSpec = null;
  }

}

module.exports = CurrentSpecReporter;
```

Add it to jasmine when you add your other reporters...

```
const CurrentSpecReporter = require('./current-spec-reporter.js');
// ...
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new CurrentSpecReporter());
```

Then extract the test name during your test/setup as needed...

```
  it('Should have an accessible description', () => {
    expect(global.currentSpec.description).toBe('Should have an accessible description');
  }
```

At last, see a sample of `currentSpec` structure:

```json
{
  "id":"spec15",
  "description":"test1",
  "fullName":"My test category test1",
  "failedExpectations":[],
  "passedExpectations":[],
  "deprecationWarnings":[],
  "pendingReason":"",
  "duration":null,
  "properties":null
}
```

Comment: This is the way to do it in Jasmine 2+.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone attempting to do this in Jasmine 2: You can introduce a subtle change to your declarations however that fix it. Instead of just doing:

```
it("name for it", function() {});
```

Define the `it` as a variable:

```
var spec = it("name for it", function() {
   console.log(spec.description); // prints "name for it"
});
```

This requires no plug-ins and works with standard Jasmine.

Comment: 'it' no longer returns the spec object, sadly.

Comment: The problem with this approach is the need to have different variables for each spec. For example   

  let spec = it('name for it', function () {
        console.log(spec.description); // prints "name for it"
    });

    spec = it('name for it 2', function () {
        console.log(spec.description); // prints "name for it"
    });

will print 'name for it 2' twice