# Jasmine2: get current spec name

Tags: jasmine, protractor

In Jasmine 1.3, we had this option to the get current spec and suite names:

```
describe("name for describe", function () {
    it("name for it", function () {
        console.log(this.suite.getFullName()); // would print "name for describe"
        console.log(this.description); // would print "name for it"
    });
});
```

This does not longer work in Jasmine 2.x.
Anyone knows how to fetch those?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I add a new jasmine reporter, then get the spec name without define N variable on each spec. Hope can help, thanks.

```
var reporterCurrentSpec = {
     specStarted: function(result) {
         this.name = result.fullName;
     }
 };
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporterCurrentSpec);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, `this` refers to `reporterCurrentSpec`, not the test.

Comment: I am not sure what @SeánHayes is referring to, but my experience is that this works just fine.

Answer (score 6):

The reason this no longer works is because `this` is not the test. You can introduce a subtle change to your declarations however that fix it. Instead of just doing:

```
it("name for it", function() {});
```

Define the `it` as a variable:

```
var spec = it("name for it", function() {
   console.log(spec.description); // prints "name for it"
});
```

This requires no plug-ins and works with standard Jasmine.

Comment: I have N number of spec and don't want that many variables. then who to do this?

Comment: [Word on the street](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742726/jasmine-how-to-get-name-of-current-test#comment58341759_32626072) is this doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @DDave Then good that `it(...)` will no longer return (in new Jasmine versions).

Answer (score 2):

As far as Jasmine 2 is concerned currentSpec is discontinued on purpose. However there is a custom plugin/library developed that is based on jasmine reporter plugin which you can use. Here's the [Link](https://github.com/bpmn-io/jasmine-test-container-support). Hope it helps with your requirement.

Its very simple to use, install the package with npm command -

**npm install -g jasmine-test-container-support**

Get the test container support by writing below lines before your **describe** or test suite -

```
var JasmineTestContainerSupport = window.JasmineTestContainerSupport || require('jasmine-test-container-support');

JasmineTestContainerSupport.extend(jasmine);
```

Later use the test container in your **spec's** to get its description -

```
var specDesc = jasmine.getEnv().getTestContainer();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var currentSpecName = describe('Test1', function() {
        var currentStepName = it("Step1", function(){
           console.log(currentStepName.description); // Prints It Name
           console.log(currentSpecName.getFullName()); //Prints Describe Name
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Posting a piece of code without any text is often not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in jasmine 3.5+

I know this is a relatively old question but found something which worked for me

```
describe('Desc1',() => {
   
    afterEach(() => {
      const myReporter = {
        specDone: (result) => {
          console.log('Spec FullName: ' + result.fullName);
          console.log('Spec Result: ' + result.status);
        }
      };
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(myReporter);
    });
})
```

Credit for the solution : https://groups.google.com/g/jasmine-js/c/qqOk6Nh7m4c/m/Nyovy2EjAgAJ

Answer (score -2):

This is probably a bit late but you can get the suite name outside the spec.
Please try the following code:

```
  describe("name for describe", function () {
    console.log(this.getFullName()); // would print "name for describe"
    it("name for it", function () {
      //Your test spec
    });
  });
```