# protractor plugin to print out filename of specfile

Tags: plugins, protractor, filenames

I'm trying to see if there is a way to print out the name of the specfile that has just finished running. I was hoping to do this in the teardown function but I am not sure how to obtain the actual filename. Does anyone have any experience with protractor plugins?

Comment: Are you looking this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118705/jasmine2-get-current-spec-name

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately jasmine reporter or protractor plugin cant give you currently executed specfile name. Only 'describe' or 'it' blocks names. Basically this is more informative than filename. Check Jasmine Custom Reporter docs - https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/custom_reporter.html

You can try to build something on your own to get filename, but maybe you should consider other options.

Comment: thank you for that input. when we use browserstack and leave the name attribute blank it seems protractor uses the name of the file so I was trying to see if that was something that was easily accessible via plugin or custom reporter for jasmine