# Get currently executed describe/test name

Tags: jasmine, jestjs

Is it possible with Jest (Jasmine) to get the currently executed name of the test or describe inside the test?

Using [Jasmine: How to get name of current test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742726/jasmine-how-to-get-name-of-current-test) is not working anymore, at least with Jest.

e.g.

```js
test('Error missing body', (done) => {
  console.log('Currently executing: ' + REFERENCE_TO_TEST_NAME);
  done();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [Get the current test/spec name in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788380/get-the-current-test-spec-name-in-jest), which albeit newer, has higher quality answers, [sourced from the Jest GitHub repo](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7774).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the current test/spec name in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788380/get-the-current-test-spec-name-in-jest)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788380/get-the-current-test-spec-name-in-jest):

```js
console.log(expect.getState().currentTestName);
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Instead of repeating an answer from a duplicate question, better to mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: I believe the referenced question is actually a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 4):

The tests are supposed to contain only the basic code for your test: Arrange / Act / Assert, so it's not a good practice to introduce this kind of code at this place. But if you want to log the currently running test, you can use the **custom_reporter** API: https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html

You can get the same result that you expect by adding this code:

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
  specStarted: function(result) {
    console.log(`Spec name: ${result.fullName}, description: ${result.description}`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
let spec = test('Error missing body', (done) => {
  console.log('Currently executing: ' +  spec.getFullName());
  done();
});
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you are checking object which isn't created yet.

Comment: Use `spec.description` instead of `spec.getFullName()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Add this in conf file for beforeTest and afterTest hooks. This worked for me:

```
beforeTest: function (test, context) {
    console.log("Execution Started for - "+test.fullName);
},
```

Answer (score -8):

```
const testParam = 'any text you need';
describe(`${testParam}`, () => {
  test('mind the backtick', () => {
    console.log(`Currently executing: ${testParam}`);
  });
});
```