# Get the current test/spec name in Jest

Tags: jestjs

Is there a way to get the current spec name from within the running test?

Basically I want to save a file, eg. using a function `saveFile()`, with the name of the file being the spec name. Without having to manually retype the name of the test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that the only possible way was through the use of `expect()`, which contains the spec name in its `this`. doing something like

```
expect.extend({
  async toSaveFile(data) {
    fs.writeFileSync(`${this.currentTestName}.txt`, data)
    return { pass: true };
  },
});
```

allows to then do

```
expect().toSaveFile('contents of the file');
```

it's definitely a hack, but it's the only way I could find to get a reference to the spec name. there is also `this.testPath` that indicates the test file

Comment: Brilliant! Nice find. I wish the jest time would document the contents available with `this` inside the `extend` call.
As far as I see, [this](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/expect/src/types.ts#L31) is the best available "documentation".

Comment: "the only possible way"? There are at least [two more ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788380/get-the-current-test-spec-name-in-jest/62694295#62694295), and one is much easier.

Comment: Not sure how long this has existed, but there's `expect.getState().currentTestName`

Comment: @ConstiP excellent!

Answer (score 32):

There's been a 2+-year old issue in the Jest repo to make the test name available, with no official solution as of Feb 2021. One core maintainer said [none would be available any time soon](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7774#issuecomment-459714689).

The community has provided workarounds, however:

## Easiest

```js
expect.getState().currentTestName
```

This will return the full path to the test, from the outermost describe to the test itself, separated with `' '` ([not](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7774#issuecomment-775757869) the best separator), e.g. `static methods toString`. You can't easily tell which one was the `describe` name, and which one was the `test` name.

## With some setup, and soon to be obsoleted

The same [GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7774#issuecomment-520780088) has this alternative method, which makes the test name accessible directly in the test via `jasmine['currentTest'].fullName`, no `extend` needed. Note though that [Jasmine will no longer be the default test reported starting in Jest 27](https://jestjs.io/blog/2020/05/05/jest-26).

### jest.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
    
    .................
};
```

### jest.setup.js:

```js
// Patch tests to include their own name
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
    specStarted: result => jasmine.currentTest = result,
    specDone: result => jasmine.currentTest = result,
});
```

### Then, in your *.test.js files...

```js
describe('Test description', () => {
    beforeEach(() => console.log('Before test', jasmine['currentTest'].fullName));

    test(...);
});
```

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me

```js
console.log(expect.getState().currentTestName);
```

Comment: Would be nice to mention [the source for that, and the caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788380/get-the-current-test-spec-name-in-jest/62694295#62694295).

Answer (score 6):

## Problem

The issue with `expect.getState().currentTestName` is that it provides a concatenated string.

So e.g. in case of `sum.test.js` test file:

```js
import { sum } from "./sum";
import { sleep } from "./util/sleep";

describe("testing sum", () => {

    describe("middle", () => {

        test('adds 1 + 1 to equal 2', async () => {

            console.log("TESTNAME", expect.getState().currentTestName)

            await sleep(1000)

            expect(sum(1, 1)).toBe(2);
        });
    })

})
```

It prints out `TESTNAME testing sum middle adds 1 + 1 to equal 2` where you cannot tell which belongs to which.

## Solution

To get the name of each test separated, this is what you can do:

### Step 1

Create custom environment. This listens to events and sets up the variable:

> Note that instead of `NodeEnvironment`, you can use `PuppeteerEnvironment` if you are using `jest-puppeteer`:
>
> ```js
> const PuppeteerEnvironment = require("jest-environment-puppeteer")
> ```

```js
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node');

class CustomEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
    constructor(config, context) {
        super(config, context);
        this.testPath = context.testPath;
        this.docblockPragmas = context.docblockPragmas;
    }

    getNames(parent) {
        if (!parent) {
            return [];
        }

        if (parent.name === 'ROOT_DESCRIBE_BLOCK') {
            return [];
        }

        const parentName = this.getNames(parent.parent);
        return [
            ...parentName,
            parent.name
        ]
    }

    async handleTestEvent(event, state) {
        const {name} = event;

        if (["test_start", "test_fn_start"].includes(name)) {
            this.global.testNames = this.getNames(event.test)
        }
    }
}

module.exports = CustomEnvironment;
```

### Step 2

Register the file in `jest.config.js`:

```js
export default {

    // ...

    // location of the file above
    testEnvironment: "./src/my-custom-environment.js",

}
```

### Step 3 (Optional for `TypeScript`)

Create `global.d.ts` file:

```js
declare const testNames: string[]
```

### Step 4

Use it in your tests:

```js
import { sum } from "./sum";
import { sleep } from "./util/sleep";

describe("testing sum", () => {

    describe("middle", () => {

        test('adds 1 + 1 to equal 2', async () => {

            console.log("TEST NAMES", testNames)

            await sleep(1000)

            expect(sum(1, 1)).toBe(2);
        });
    })

})
```

Output:

```
TEST NAMES [ 'testing sum', 'middle', 'adds 1 + 1 to equal 2' ]
```

---

Credits goes to:

- [Dan, for linking the Github issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62694295/4420543)
- [`billyvg`, for posting their solution](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7774#issuecomment-857183762)

Comment: I'd think this would be a problem if jest tests are running in parallel

Comment: You can also retrieve the value by casting `(global as any).testNames` instead of resorting to global.d.ts