# Jest - Get Test and Description Name

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to get the name of the test name that was passed into `it(name: string)` Jest function, as well as the description name that was passed into `describe(name: string, ....)`.

Is there a way to access this somehow?

E.g.

```
describe("Description", () => {
  it("Test", () => {

    const description = "How do I get the description name?"
    const test = "How do I get the test name?";

    expect(`${description} - ${test}`).toBe("Description - Test");
  });
})
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-moser-hjjke?fontsize=14&module=%2Findex.test.ts&previewwindow=tests&view=editor)

**Update 1**

Underlying reason why I want this is because I want to do some custom snapshot naming conventions based on describe, test, and some environment variables (e.g. viewport sizes + mock/real data).

Comment: How exactly are you planning on using this? You could store it in a closure variable, but not sure if that'll meet your needs? However, in terms of the describe block, use an actual `function () {}` instead of an arrow function and you can call `this.description`. For example, `describe('hi', function () { console.log(this.description); })` However this does not work with a `test`/`it` block.

Comment: I want to create a helper method for snapshot naming based on dynamic data/env variables as well as the Test + Description name

Comment: I might be able to use `expect.extend()` which binds `this` and has `testPath: "/index.test.ts"` and `currentTestName: "Description Test"`

Comment: Dupe of [How to get the current spec name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788380/how-to-get-the-current-spec-name), and I've just posted a new answer over there.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using a custom matcher

```
expect.extend({
  testName(exp) {
      return {
          pass: this.currentTestName === exp,
          message: () => '',
      };
  },
});

describe("Description", () => {
  it("Test", () => {
      expect(`Description Test`).testName();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, the most obvious solution is what you want. Instead of passing literals to `describe` and `it` just store them in a respective constants which could then be easily accessed inside the respective test cases though the outer scope.

These constants could be easily initialized either by values from the environmental variables or by literal defaults.

```
const suiteA = 'Description';
describe(suiteA, () => {
  const testA = 'Test';
  it(testA, () => {
    expect(`${suiteA} - ${testA}`).toBe("Description - Test");
  });
})
```

Comment: Yeah but you have to define a constant for every test. There's an [easier way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788380/get-the-current-test-spec-name-in-jest/62694295#62694295).