# How can I make a Jest JS test fail if its name is too long or contains certain characters?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, continuous-integration

We have tools as part of our CI/CD pipeline that process our Jest output.

One of these tools has some strict rules on the the test name, such as length must be below 255 characters and no special characters. In some cases, like using `it.each()`, it can be easy to construct a test name that might violate these conditions without realising. The downstream tool then rejects such tests with a log message, if you know what you're looking for... so from a developer's perspective it's silent / they are unaware there's an issue.

We are unlikely to get the tool to change their approach, so I'd like to make this a hard stop as early as I can in the test pipeline. I know I can do some processing of the reporter output, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make the test itself fail so it makes it super clear to the developer where the issue is. I appreciate that having tests fail for reasons outside of what's actually being tested is a bit conceptually grey, but has advantages in terms of usability for us.

I couldn't see any obvious wat to do this in the Jest documentation, but may have missed something. Is there any way to accomplish this within Jest itself? Or would it have to be done as report post-processing?

Comment: you should check these 2 questions out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57299503/jest-get-test-and-description-name and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788380/get-the-current-test-spec-name-in-jest/62694295#62694295

Comment: Thanks for these, I see from those I can get the current tests name in the test. I'd rather not add manually add an additional expectation onto each test manually. But from those looks like I could maybe hook into the `handleTestEvent` in the jest environment, and throwing an exception if the test name is "invalid"... would that be a reasonable approach?

Comment: yes, adding an additional expectation won't be ideal so hooking into the event seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this through using the `setupFilesAfterEnv` config property and the following code:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  expect(expect.getState().currentTestName).toMatch(/^[^&<>]{10,255}$/)
})
```

It works well enough to solve my problem and can be consistently applied in our code structure.