# How to get current test index in jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

How do I get index of current test in `test.each` in `jest`

This is how I'm doing at the moment

```js
test.each([
  [ "Adam", 0 ], // specifying index manually
  [ "Ron", 1 ],
  [ "Roy", 2 ],
])( "Student: %s", ( name, currentTestIndex, done ) => {
  if ( currentTestIndex == 0 ) expect( name ).toEqual( "Adam" )
  if ( currentTestIndex == 2 ) expect( name ).toEqual( "Roy" );
  return done()
} )
```

How to do it without specifying the index manually

```js
test.each([
  [ "Adam"], // not specifying the index
  [ "Ron" ],
  [ "Roy" ],
])( "Student: %s", ( name, currentTestIndex, done ) => {

  // how to get current test's index ?
  if ( currentTestIndex == 0 ) expect( name ).toEqual( "Adam" )
  if ( currentTestIndex == 2 ) expect( name ).toEqual( "Roy" );
  return done()
} )
```

Edit:

Doing it this way now, by creating another array with `map` and adding index as the first element

```js
test.each([
  [ "Adam" ],
  [ "Ron"  ],
  [ "Roy"  ],
].map( (eachArr,ind) => { //creating new array and adding index as the 1st element
  eachArr.unshift( ind ); 
  return eachArr;
}))( "Student: %s", ( currentTestIndex, name, done ) => {
  if ( currentTestIndex == 0 ) expect( name ).toEqual( "Adam" )
  if ( currentTestIndex == 2 ) expect( name ).toEqual( "Roy" );
  return done()
});
```

any other way to get the index, from `jest` itself without creating  a new array like above?

Comment: Based on the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout), it doesn't seem to be possible. I would use the automatic mapper like you're using now, but I would make it a function that can be reused, and fix the issue of mutating `eachArr`: `const indexer = (table) => table.map((row, idx) => [...row, idx]);` and calling it as `test.each(indexer(table))(...)`

Comment: @Samathingamajig, yes having a function makes sense and thanks for pointing out the mutating issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon this answer, which shows how to get the [name of the current test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63625415/6885192)

> console.log(expect.getState().currentTestName);

---

So now we just add this [index place holder](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#1-describeeachtablename-fn-timeout) in the name of the test

> %# - Index of the test case.

---

```js
function getCurrentTestIndex() {
  const testName = expect.getState().currentTestName;
  const testIndexPos = testName.lastIndexOf(":")+1;
  const currentTestIndex = parseInt( testName.substring( testIndexPos ) )
  return currentTestIndex;
}


test.each(["Adam", "Ron", "Roy"])( "Student: %s :%#", ( name, done ) => {
  const currentTestIndex = getCurrentTestIndex();
  if ( currentTestIndex == 0 ) expect( name ).toEqual( "Adam" )
  if ( currentTestIndex == 2 ) expect( name ).toEqual( "Roy" )

  return done()
})
```

You could keep the `getCurrentTestIndex()` in global if you want to use it across your test files and would like to avoid writing import statement everywhere

> global.getCurrentTestIndex = getCurrentTestIndex;

---

So now we are getting the index from jest itself, but we have to add the index in the test name and extract it.

But it would certainly be nicer to get `currentTestIndex` in similar manner as how we can get the `currentTestName`.

---

In case if you are looking for one liner

```js
getCurrentTestIndex = _ => parseInt( expect.getState().currentTestName.split(":").at(-1) )
```

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else's looking for this, declaring the index outside should do the trick:

```
let currentTestIndex = 0

test.each(["Adam", "Ron", "Roy"])( "Student: %s", ( name, done ) => {
    if ( currentTestIndex == 0 ) expect( name ).toEqual( "Adam" )
    if ( currentTestIndex == 2 ) expect( name ).toEqual( "Roy" )

    currentTestIndex += 1

    return done()
})
```

Comment: It just feels like there must be a better way

Comment: workarounds with `let` are not the best way to deal with indexes

Answer (score 3):

## Get the index of the current array element in the test suite

```js
const MOCK_DATA = [
    {
        key: 'item_1',
        value: 'value_1',
    },
    {
        key: 'item_2',
        value: 'value_2',
    },
    {
        key: 'item_3',
        value: 'value_3',
    },
]

describe.each(MOCK_DATA)('item № %#',item => {
    it('your test case', () => {
        /* ... */

        /**
         * one of ways to get the index of the current array element
         *
         *                             ↓↓↓
         */
        const currentIndex = MOCK_DATA.indexOf(item)

        /* ... */
    });
})
```

I'm not sure if the index of the test case can differ from the index of the array element used in the test case. Therefore, the option below is also appropriate.

## Get the index of the current test case in the test suite

[The workaround by @kaushik-r-bangera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75313857/14140292)

Comment: Well recall of `indexOf`!